# Fail to yum install libstdc++.so.6 when installing db2 v11.5 in redhat OS

Tags: linux, rhel, software-installation, yum, db2

Good day,

I am trying to install DB2 V11.5 (64 bit) in red hat OS.

However, I having some warning message as follow:

```
Summary of prerequisites that are not met on the current system:

   DBT3514W  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following 32-bit library file: "/lib/libpam.so*".

DBT3514W  The db2prereqcheck utility failed to find the following 32-bit library file: "libstdc++.so.6".
```

Then I go to do `yum install libstdc++.i686`, but hitting another error which is as follow:
[image]

Not understand that why the system hitting 32 bit error when I am installing 64 bits DB2. And My OS is redhat 64 bits:
[image]

Kindly advise how can I continue to fix this issue? 
Edit **
I downloaded the db2 v11.5 from IBM website, the file name will be as follow:
DB2_Svr_11.5_Linux_x86-64.tar

Comment: All of the information you have posted points to the DB2 package you are attempting to install being 32-bit.  Please show the specific package you are trying to install and where it came from if you believe otherwise.

Comment: @GracefulRestart , I am downloaded the installer from IBM website, the file name is DB2_Svr_11.5_Linux_x86-64.tar, I believe this is 64 bits right?

Comment: A tar file would not initiate a YUM install.  What is the command you ran to trigger the error you have posted?  There should be some kind of reference to an RPM package or YUM command.

Comment: Apologies, after reading about DB2, it does indeed require being able to run 32-bit PAM which would also need the full 32-bit subsystem installed.  Your issue with installing `libstdc++.i686` looks to be rooted in your current package versions (from RHEL 7.5) versus the package versions in your configured repositories (RHEL 7.3).  Your configured repositories are offering packages older than what you have installed and causing conflicts.

Comment: Hi @GracefulRestart , can I said that I should configure the repositories to newer so that I can install the libstdc++.i686 successfully?

Comment: Hi @GracefulRestart , could you share me the document talking about require libstdc++.i686 for this db2 installation? Sorry I am trying to search for it but cant get. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [This is the IBM document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0008865.html) I was referencing in my comment.  As for the repositories, the DB2 documentation says it only works on RedHat 7.5+ (which you have installed), but your repositories seem to be pointing to RedHat 7.3 (so it cannot get the proper versions of required dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not intend to use 32-bit applications with DB2 database, then no action is required and the warning message can be ignored.

The installation will complete successfully. I just installed 11.5.4.0, the latest version of DB2 at the moment.